# Magento2 : Layout block what is the difference between acl="" and aclResource"" attribute

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, acl, aclresource

I've been trying to figure out the difference between `acl` and `aclResource` both attributes available for `<block>` directive.

I know that aclResource is useful to render the block based on specific acl resource_id example :

```xml
<block name="my_block" aclResource="Some_Module::default">
```

see example in [magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/MediaGalleryUi/view/adminhtml/layout/media_gallery_index_index.xml#L14)

I see that the same attribute is also used in blocks inside ui_components like following :

```xml
<uiComponent name="notification_area" aclResource="Magento_AdminNotification::show_list"/>
```

see example in [magento](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/AdminNotification/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml#L11)

Now by looking at the [XSD](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd#L215) file of layout for block handle I see acl and aclResource for the block type

```xml
    <xs:complexType name="blockType" mixed="true">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>
        ....
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="elementNameType" name="name" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="blockClassType" name="class" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="elementAliasType" name="as" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="template" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="elementPositionType" name="before" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="elementPositionType" name="after" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="elementOutputType" name="output" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="acl" use="optional"/> <!-- here -->
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="aclResource" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ifconfig" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="group" use="optional" />
        <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="cacheable" default="true" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:int" name="ttl" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

by searching in magento core for usages of `acl="` in blocks but only in [customer_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml#L10) which is a form ui component.

```xml
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <htmlContent name="orders_content">
        <block acl="Magento_Sales::actions_view" class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\CustomerOrdersTab" name="orders" />
    </htmlContent>
    <htmlContent name="cart_content">
        <block acl="Magento_Cart::manage" class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\ShoppingCartsTab" name="cart"/>
    </htmlContent>
</form>
```

All that said, my question(s) is :
does acl and aclResource do the same ? is there any rule or best practice to use one above the other ? is acl deprecated ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
minutes after posting the question I found out that :

- the `acl` attribute is deprecated and had same role as `aclResource`
  see : [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Reader/Block.php#L87)

```php
...
    const ATTRIBUTE_ACL = 'aclResource';
...
    /**
     * @deprecated 101.0.0
     * @var string
     */
    private $deprecatedAttributeAcl = 'acl';

...

    /**
     * Replaces old ACL attribute key to new.
     *
     * @param array|Element $data
     *
     * @return array|Element
     */
    private function replaceDeprecatedAclKey($data)
    {
        if (isset($data[$this->deprecatedAttributeAcl])) {
            $data[self::ATTRIBUTE_ACL] = (string)$data[$this->deprecatedAttributeAcl];
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

So in conclusion only aclResouce should be used in block to stay future proof.